# heroku router - - at=error code=H12 - Site going down for 30s every day or two

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

Heroku Rails site going down every day or two for 30 seconds max, alerts sent by uptime-robot.

Have tried to run some basic load testing, and doesn't seem take the site down when under solid traffic. Not running any expensive queries on the homepage.

Error logs look like the below. Running rails on hobby dev.
Not getting any errors through New Relic. Running Puma 'puma', '~> 2.15.3'. 
Have this set on rack timeout initailizer: Rack::Timeout.timeout = 15

> Dec 07 20:14:46 sleepy-wave-3748 heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=mySiteUrlHere request_id=274ed877-2edb-43f2-8b77-c7a82f17109a fwd="69.162.124.231,108.162.221.131" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30007ms status=503 bytes=0
>
> Dec 07 20:35:46 sleepy-wave-3748 heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=HEAD path="/" host=mySiteUrlHere request_id=1b43b249-f089-4a4a-a42b-b2886d607fa8 fwd="69.162.124.231,108.162.221.131" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved it. I found a pull request in the Puma github account relating to this issue and noticed the fix had been included in a later version of Puma. After upgrading my Puma version, the problem has stopped happening. Hopefully this can help someone else out.

Note, I upgraded to Puma 2.15.3 from 2.11.2 .

Answer (score 2):

Heroku will typically disconnect after 30 seconds and return a 503 error. It appears that your service may be responding successfully but after 30 seconds have passed. This could explain why you are not seeing application errors but are seeing Heroku errors.

EDIT: I think I may have misread your question. Heroku goes through a cycling process on some of its dynos. During this time, there may be a possibility for it to appear that your application has gone down. If you are using free dynos, they require a period of downtime (per rolling 24hr period)

Comment: Thanks @DvideBy0.
I am on the hobby plan, which Horoku says "Never sleeps", however I am not sure if this means it won't get 'cycled' or not. 


I also get notification about H12 errors on some assets such as this:
` heroku router - - at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/assets/logo-black-7ba65886b63580ff901df4e9ca061200.png" host=SiteUrlHere request_id=4f7dc65c-1cec-4e3f-a0f7-39df93b4fbf2 fwd="114.134.6.64,198.41.238.104" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0`